# C++ interface to a linear memory buffer

Tags: c++, object, memory, data-structures

I have a large dataset that I want to keep in a contiguous linear memory buffer. This memory buffer takes the form of an STL vector.

The dataset is grouped in a hierarchy:

```
increment--->image number--->pixel number
```

There are 100 increments, 10 images per increment, and each image has 320x240 pixels.

Besides doing the following (obtuse) way to access a specific pixel element of the linear memory buffer:

```
buffer[increment*image_number*320*240 + column_number*240+row_number]
```

Is there a more intuitive interface to access specific pixel elements of this buffer while keeping the data contiguous?

Comment: It's considered polite to give feedback to answeres ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple interface overloading `operator()`:

```
PixelData& operator()(size_t increment, size_t image_number, size_t row_number, size_t column_number)
{
    return buffer[increment*image_number*320*240 + column_number*240+row_number];
}
```

This way, a pixel could be accessed with:

```
dataset(increment, img, row, column);
```

Comment: The subscript operator [] cannot be overloaded with multiple arguments. One could use the function operator (), but this can cause confusion. Probably better to create a member function that does this operation.

Comment: @user1431515 you're right, I've edited my answer as a consequence. Regarding the confusion, you can find [multiple sources](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) in [favour of `operator()`](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/99-overloading-the-parenthesis-operator/).